# Cube root of negative real numbers

Tags: python, sympy, python-3.5

I'm trying to plot a quite complex function, i.e. `log(x/(x-2))**Rational(1,3)`.  I'm working only with real numbers. If I try to plot it, `sympy` only plots the **x>2 part** of it.

I found that actually complex numbers come into play and, for example,`root(-8,3).n()` gives:

> 1.0+1.73205080756888i

Which is reasonable, even though it's not what I was looking for (because I'm only interested in the real result).

Reading [sympy › principle root](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sympy/7MgDY2AKPzA) I found that `real_root(-8,3)` gives `-2` as expected. But I still cannot plot the **x<0 part** of that function; in fact it seems that `real_root` only works for integer roots, and `real_root(-9,3).n()` still gives an imaginary result, instead of `-(real_root(9, 3))` as I would expect.

I thought a real result existed for (-9)^(1/3) and I don't understand why `real_root` gives an imaginary result instead.

Is there a simple way to get a schoolbook result for the cube root of real negative numbers, like  (-x)^(1/3) = - (x)^(1/3)?

**Edit**:
Following @Leon 's suggestion: I updated `sympy` and could actually calculate the real cube root of -9.
But still I cannot plot the function I mentioned at the beginning of the topic.

```
from sympy import *
var('x')
f=real_root((log(x/(x-2))), 3)
plot(f)
```

gives an error like `NameError: name 'Ne' is not defined`.
I noticed that trying to print `f` results in

```
Piecewise((1, Ne(arg(x/(x - 2)), 0)), ((-1)**(2/3), log(x/(x - 2)) < 0), (1, True))*log(x/(x - 2))**(1/3)
```

Does that `Ne` have something to do with my error?

Comment: With Python 2.7.10, SymPy 1.0 there is no such problem: `sympy.real_root(-9,3).n()` returns `-2.08008382305190`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I forgot to mention I'm using Python 3.5.
After updating `conda` and `anaconda` (and hence `sympy`), I was also able to compute the cube root of 9.   

Anyway, 

`from sympy import *`

`f=real_root(log(x/(x-2)), 3)`

`plot(f)`

gives a very complicated error message I cannot understand!

Comment: The message you are seeing is a bug in SymPy. I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/11461).

Comment: I asked a similar question, some might even say a duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38682936/cube-root-of-negative-real-numbers/38707315 The answer there provides a workaround to this problem in real_root().

Answer (score 3):

It seems SymPy's plot has a bug, so for now, you'll have to use `lambdify` and `matplotlib` to plot it manually:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = lambdify(x, (real_root((log(x/(x-2))), 3)), 'numpy')
vals = np.linspace(2, 10, 1000)
plt.plot(vals, f(vals))
```

This gives some warnings because the 2 value at the end point is a singularity, and also warns that if you have a complex number that the imaginary part is ignored.

Here is the plot[image]

Comment: Your solution works great for positive numbers, but still I cannot get a plot for that function with `x<0` .
For example, if you substitute `np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)`, the errors are `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
  """` and `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
  """`

Comment: It looks like the formula SymPy is using for real_root is giving `nan+nan*j` when evaluated with NumPy at negative values of x.