# Plot a cube root function with SymPy, including negative arguments

Tags: sympy

I'm trying to plot a cube root function with SymPy. I know what this should look like, but I'm only seeing values for x >= 0, not for negative numbers. I've tried two approaches.

**cbrt:**

```
from sympy import symbols, plot
from sympy.functions.elementary.miscellaneous import cbrt

x    = symbols('x')
eqn  = cbrt(x)
p    = plot(eqn)
```

**nthroot:**

```
from sympy import symbols, plot
from sympy.simplify.simplify import nthroot

x    = symbols('x')
eqn  = nthroot(x, 3)
p    = plot(eqn)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SymPy's functions `cbrt` and `root` use the [principal branch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_branch) of the root. The principal branch of the multivalued function `z->z**(1/3)` is equal to `-1/2 + I*sqrt(3)/2` at -1. It is not a real number, so you don't see it on the plot.

But it is often desired to get the real-valued root for all real inputs, which is possible for odd degrees. This is provided by the function [`real_root`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#real-root). So, **in principle** your code should be

```
from sympy import symbols, plot, real_root
x    = symbols('x')
eqn  = real_root(x, 3)
p    = plot(eqn)
```

However, the implementation of `real_root` does not fit the expectations of the SymPy plotting routine, so the above throws an error as of now. (Different errors in different versions of SymPy). Instead, plot the mathematically equivalent function `|x|**(1/3) * sign(x)`:

```
from sympy import symbols, plot, root, sign, Abs
x    = symbols('x')
eqn  = root(Abs(x), 3)*sign(x)
p    = plot(eqn)
```

[image: plot]

Remark:   The function `nthroot` from `simplify` module is not for computing the nth root, it is for simplifying expressions with radicals.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seems that my question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38682936/cube-root-of-negative-real-numbers/38707315 but your workaround provides a solution to the plotting problem. I added a note there.